# How to ensure backward compatibility after implementing URL rewrite?

Tags: php, url-routing

I am planning to make clean URLs with htaccess as in [php url routing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741414/php-url-routing-question) .

I would change from:

```
/movies/index.php?id=iron_man
/movies/iron_man
```

But the old-style links are already on the interwebs. What would happen when I access

```
/movies/index.php?id=iron_man
```

when htaccess is in place?

---

Do I have to be concerned with **identifying and redirecting** the old-sytle links, when a request appears? If so, how do I do it?

And can I set it to 301 redirects (which avoids SEO penalties)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be concerned or you will lose value from links pointing to those URLs. You should definitly spend time to redirect using a 301 header to the new URL using:

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/movies/iron_man', false, 301);
```

The easiest way it to let your old rewrite point to a script handling all movie redirects.